Sudoku variants #3: Schrödinger's Grave Remastered (8x8 grid)
Previous variant
Originally inspired by Cracking the Cryptic's video "The Graveyard of Schrödinger" (original gimmick by fjam)

Background

On Nov. 6, 2023 (1 year ago!), I posted the puzzle "Sudoku variants #1: Schrödinger's Grave (6x6 grid)", which was a Sudoku variant puzzle dedicated to an odd Sudoku variant that I had taken interest in.
However, I had not fully understood the ruleset at the time, and ended up accidentally making the puzzle impossible. Because of this, I have been studying the ruleset so I could actually make a solvable puzzle based on this gimmick. The puzzle has been playtested to make sure that it is actually solvable without the use of a computer, along with making sure that it is actually solvable in the first place.
I have also made sure to create the puzzle in a document online so I don't lose the solution sheet as easily.

Ruleset


Normal sudoku rules almost apply.

Place the digits 0-8 into cells such that each digit appears once in every row, column and region. To accommodate this, one cell in each row, column and region (box) is a Schrödinger cell, which contains two digits.
In graves (cages), digits must sum to the day, month or year of the date on the grave. Digits cannot repeat within graves.


If a grave contains a Schrödinger cell, then both digits in that cell also contribute to the sum.


Escape the graveyard by carefully plotting an orthogonally connected path between the green and red cells. The path may not cross the highest or lowest digits in a grave.



The puzzle (8x8)

How the boxes are going to be split up:
Box 1: R1C1, R1C2, R1C3, R1C4    Box 2: R1C5, R1C6, R1C7, R1C8
       R2C1, R2C2, R2C3, R2C4           R2C5, R2C6, R2C7, R2C8

Box 3: R3C1, R3C2, R3C3, R3C4    Box 4: R3C5, R3C6, R3C7, R3C8
       R4C1, R4C2, R4C3, R4C4           R4C5, R4C6, R4C7, R4C8

Box 5: R5C1, R5C2, R5C3, R5C4    Box 6: R5C5, R5C6, R5C7, R5C8
       R6C1, R6C2, R6C3, R6C4           R6C1, R6C2, R6C3, R6C4

Box 7: R7C1, R7C2, R7C3, R7C4    Box 8: R7C1, R7C2, R7C3, R7C4
       R8C1, R8C2, R8C3, R8C4           R8C1, R8C2, R8C3, R8C4

Rows are ordered from top to bottom, columns are ordered from left to right















$\color{green}✓$
12/14/08
09/08/16
09/08/16
09/08/16
10/20/67
10/20/67
08/16/49


01/05/10
12/14/08
09/08/16
11/30/19
10/20/67
10/20/67
08/16/49
08/16/49


01/05/10
06/24/14
11/30/19
11/30/19
01/06/09
01/06/09
01/21/17
08/16/49


06/24/14
06/24/14
11/30/19
04/24/18
04/24/18
04/24/18
01/21/17
01/21/17


02/28/13
12/08/29
06/11/12
06/11/12
03/22/14
04/24/18
01/21/17
09/08/26


02/28/13
12/08/29
05/06/24
03/22/14
03/22/14
03/22/14
07/20/09
09/08/26


02/28/13
12/08/29
05/06/24
10/25/43
03/22/14
07/20/09
07/20/09
07/20/09


02/28/13
02/28/13
05/06/24
10/25/43
10/25/43
04/07/08
04/07/08
$\color{red}✓$



Image of the puzzle if the table ends up being too compressed for the dates to be readable (with highlighted grave borders):



The original puzzle by fjam can be found here.

Solving links


Penpa (Includes answer check)

Note: Numbers in Schrödinger cells are entered by clicking "Centre" in Sudoku mode, and then by inputting both numbers. Original Penpa link by @SquareFinder.

SudokuPad link

Note: Numbers in Schrödinger cells are inputted using the same method above (here by clicking the [12] box).

"digits 0-6"? That's only seven different digits, but the rows, columns and boxes have eight cells each. (Plus we need an eighth one to accommodate the double cells)

@ilkkachu Sorry, I meant 0-8

Penpa link for those who want it

In a grave with 2 cells, each cell contains either the smallest or highest digit of the grave. Since the path starting from the green cell must pass through a grave having two cells, wouldn't Rule 3 not be satisfied?

@TLEontest77 Rule 3 is indeed satisfied. If it passes through a 2-cell grave, then that grave has a Schrödinger cell

This should probably be a comment, but I'm pretty new so I don't have enough reputation yet.
Any chance we could get a hint as to where to start? I've spent many hours over the past two weeks looking at this puzzle and still can't find a break-in point.
What I've deduced so far:

 1. The 12/14/08 grave (next to green square) must contain a Schrödinger cell

 2. It could be either one. If the top cell (R1C2) is a Schrödinger, then R3C1 must also be a Schrödinger. If it's the bottom cell (R2C2), then R3C1 may or may not be one.

 3. Because 12/14/08 contains a Schrödinger, the 12/08/29 grave below it in R5-7 cannot contain one. This means the sum of that grave cannot be 29, it must be 12 or 8.

I've also eliminated some of the numbers (DD,MM,YY) from some of the graves since they're impossible to achieve with the given number of cells.
I solved the original puzzle you linked - it was tough, but manageable. This one seems much, much harder.

Admittedly this is much more difficult due to the fact that there are more graves that go off into other boxes, meaning that there are more restrictions. However I would like to note that your current logic is correct so far, so good job!

Also don't worry, IMO this is good for a partial answer, doesn't need to be a comment here.

About the hint you wanted: Look at the last rule in the given ruleset. What does that tell you about the 12/14/08 grave?

I'm not sure what further information that rule can tell me besides what I already listed in my answer. Starting from the green square, the path can go one of two ways: (1) down to R2C1, then right to R2C2 (in which case the top cell of 12/14/08, R1C2, is a Schrödinger); or, (2) right to R1C2, in which case the bottom cell, R2C2, is a Schrödinger. I've tried following both cases to see if one can be eliminated, but haven't found any contradictions in either one yet. Maybe I haven't completely understood the given ruleset? I've seriously been banging my head against this for so many hours...
